# python pip install is working only for 64 bit and not 32 bit

Tags: python, python-import

I was doing a project in python and saw that `import IPy` was not working in 32-bit python IDLE. When I tried to do it in 64-bit python IDLE it worked. I installed IPy using `pip install IPy` in cmd. This was my python 32-bit IDLE console input and output:

```
>>> from IPy import IP
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPy'
```

I am using Windows 7 and Python 3.8 in both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Your pip usually points to the last python installation you did. Which might be the 64-bit one, then only in that python IPy is installed. Use the proper python interpreter and install . For eg. `C:\Python-32\bin\python.exe -m pip install IPy`

Comment: @Kris When i run the command it shows the Win Error 2.Thank you for trying to help

Comment: Please, its not a full proper command, find your python install path and use accordingly.

Comment: @Kris Yes i have gone to the correct path and have run the code correctly but did not work

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @Kris its showing: ERROR: Error [WinError2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command python setup.py egg_info...ERROR:Could not install pakages due to an OSError: [WinError2] The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Try setting up a virtual env for the python first and install ? I think your python executable has some PATH issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must install a new virtual environment. Give huge credits to @Kris.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).